# On which port my web application is running asp.net C#

Tags: c#, port

Is there a way to find out on which port my web application is running using C# code as I like to write it in integer variable?

Comment: They run on port 80 or 443 for HTTP and HTTPS respectively. Can you please clarify.

Comment: The application is running on different port almost every time.I like to write the port number in some integer variable?

Comment: Then can you clarify what this app is doing? BEcause if it is a webapp running ASP.NET, it should be 80 or 443.

Comment: My application is running on localhost I only like to send mail to users when they are registered for the url of the login page .One of the answers below help me

Comment: BTW... the builtin IIS that you use to debug your application inside visual studio will not let external users (even local network) connect to your site. You have to run it on regular IIS. You may have already known that, but if you didn't that may save you some time.

Answer (score 3):

You can get it this way, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx), If you could not see port in url it means the port is 80.

```
int port =  Request.Url.Port;
```

or you can get from url

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.mywebsite.com:80/pages/page1.aspx");
int port  = uri.Port;
```

Comment: @vikifor you might want to accept this as answer if it helped solving your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you running from Visual Studio then every time it will pick up a new port number, once you have deployed your application then it will pick up the port given for your website.

The default port is `80`.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the port in project settings if you use Visual Studio Development Server
or choose the port in IIS settings.